# Created new query to search two tables using access wizard but it doesnt work in program?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

I have written a query for an access database using the access query maker. Previously I only needed to query one table and all of my code ran perfectly using an old query, however the new query I have created does not run.This leads me to believe the problem is with the query itself. The query does work in access so I am unsure what the problem is. I believe the problem may be that the query is for SQL and and I am using OleDb but I don't have enough experience with either to recognize the difference.

my query is:

```
SELECT
  Chapters.ChapterName,
  ChapterScores.ChapterNo,
  ChapterScores.AllTimeScore,
  ChapterScores.TotalAttempted,
  ChapterScores.Unlocked
FROM Chapters
INNER JOIN ChapterScores
  ON (Chapters.ModuleID = ChapterScores.ModuleID)
  AND (Chapters.ChapterNo = ChapterScores.ChapterNo)
WHERE (((ChapterScores.ModuleID) = '"+modulename+"')
AND ((Chapters.ModuleID) = [ChapterScores].[ModuleID])
AND ((Chapters.ChapterNo) = [ChapterScores].[ChapterNo])
AND ((ChapterScores.UserID) = '"+LoginForm.UserID+"'));
```

`loginForm.UserID` is an `int32` and `modulename` is a string.

Links to see what the two tables look like are below

[image: Chapters Table,]
[image: Chapter Scores Table]

in the program the code looks like this:

```
OleDbDataReader Reader2;
var getscore = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Chapters.ChapterName, ChapterScores.ChapterNo, ChapterScores.AllTimeScore, ChapterScores.TotalAttempted, ChapterScores.Unlocked FROM Chapters INNER JOIN ChapterScores ON(Chapters.ModuleID = ChapterScores.ModuleID) AND(Chapters.ChapterNo = ChapterScores.ChapterNo) WHERE(((ChapterScores.ModuleID) = '"+modulename+"') AND((Chapters.ModuleID) =[ChapterScores].[ModuleID]) AND((Chapters.ChapterNo) =[ChapterScores].[ChapterNo]) AND((ChapterScores.UserID) = '"+LoginForm.UserID+"'));", connection);

Reader2 = getscore.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader2.Read())
{
   Console.WriteLine(Reader2.GetValue(0));
}
```

Comment: What exactly is meant by "not working" - do you get an error? Are you not getting the expected result? What _are_ the expected results?

Comment: what does it mean it does not work ? Do you get an error message ? Or not the results you expect ? Or no results ? or what ?

Comment: all I get is this Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll

Comment: Is that the entire message ?

Comment: I have been trying to write the values queried in the console but all i get is this error when I read the data base using a datareader

Comment: yes: Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll

Comment: aha now we are getting somewhere. You have some code written so show us that code how else can anybody help you

Comment: You should edit your question and put the code you are using there. Also tell us at what line of code the exception occurs

Comment: I have edited the question to add a simplified version of the code, using breakpoints I was unable to tell exactly where the exception occurs but it is definitely around the query

Comment: Use parameters. The error is likely caused by you using string delimiters around a field that isn't a string in the database, but using parameters avoids that issue altogether.

Comment: you should debug this code and then you can tell exact on what line the exception occurs

Comment: it was the delimiter!!! Thanks!!!!